# How a wireless NIC works on the hardware level and the capabilities?

Tags: c, networking, assembly

I couldn't think of a better title name, but to the point.

I wanted to know how the wireless NIC/NIC operates with the system it is connected to (not over a connection, but an internal one or a pci, or usb, or any other peripheral), and what can the card itself do with the system (besides connecting to some router or AP, or anything not dealing with the hardware internals), or what it can communicate to the local system?

I'm not sure if these are defined at the assembly level or in the user-space level, so I would also like to know that as well, if possible.

Comment: Start here: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI-X)

Comment: What is next, my friend?

Comment: Probably good to know what the wireless card is saying to other wireless cards: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External wireless NICs attach over USB; internal ones typically use PCI or PCIe.

The details of how these devices communicate with the host are all device-specific. In many cases, the NIC runs a firmware which the host must upload to the device at startup. The details of what this firmware must contain are basically never documented. A few wireless NICs (typically the older ones) actually implement hardware commands to perform operations like associating with an AP, but most do not.

There are no standards here. Every device is a little bit different. There is also almost never any documentation. If you want to learn more, your best bet is to find the source code for a Linux driver for the device you're interested in, dig into it, and hope it's well-commented.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend! I have been spending days on this topic and this is pointing me in a very useful direction!